# Simple inheritance does not work between projects

Tags: c#, inheritance

I just know I'm being an idiot, so somebody please tell me how.

Setup is simple:

1. Create a solution with three projects (.Net framework, class libraries) named `InherTest`, `InherTest.Base`, and `InherTest.Base.Inherited`
2. In `InherTest.Base`, add the following class:

   namespace InherTest.Base
   {
       public abstract class BaseClass
       {
           internal abstract string MEMBER_1 { get; }
       }
   }
3. Copy the exact same code into `InherTest`, including the namespace.
4. In `InherTest.Base.Inherited`, add the following class:

   namespace InherTest.Base.Inherited
   {
       public class Inherited : BaseClass
       {
           internal override string MEMBER_1 { get; }
       }
   }
5. Add a project reference in `InherTest.Base.Inherited` to `InherTest.Base`. Note the errors ("abstract member not implemented" and "no suitable member found to override").
6. Remove that reference and replace it with one to `InherTest`. Observe that the inheritance **also fails**.

Why don't they both work?

Edit: Originally I stated that one test would fail and the other would succeed; however, both inheritance attempts fail in the above scenario.

Comment: `MEMBER_1` should be declared `public`

Comment: `Why don't they both work?` <= They should both fail if they contain the same code as you claim. If that is not the case then the code **is** different between the 2 projects, specifically the `MEMBER_1` is probably declared as `public` in `InherTest` project. Alternatively you have an assembly level attribute `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("InherTest.Base.Inherited")]` in the project `InherTest`

Comment: @Igor is right. I created a solution according to your instructions and they both fail, for the reason given by Rahul and Dale.

Comment: @Igor you're right, I've corrected the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the string is `internal` so limited to it's own project

Comment: Thanks @Dale. I see the issue, but that still left me with a problem. Since the base class was in another assembly, I had to change the member to `Public` (which I didn't want) so it could be inherited. The best solution I could find was to create a Shared Project with the base class so it would be included in any assembly that referenced it.

Comment: You can use `protected internal` , or just `protected` if only derived classes need access to it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't they both work?

They should both fail if they contain the same code as you claim. If that is not the case then the code **is** different between the 2 projects, specifically the `MEMBER_1` is probably declared as `public` in `InherTest` project.

The only way that a reference to `InherTest` would work with the same code you posted is if you have this assembly level attribute [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) in the project `InherTest`

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("InherTest.Base.Inherited")]
```

Answer (score -2):

Inherited Namespaces are in different project. (Name spaces seems like together but they are not in a same assembly). You can read that article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal

Comment: `internal` refers to *assemblies*, not namespaces. Not my downvote btw

Comment: "Create a solution with three projects" Sorry I mean becuase of these three different projects (they seems like same namespace but they are not in same assembly)